# What does sCount=2 dsCount=1 mean in android ANR file?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-debug, android-anr-dialog

I have some problem with an ANR files, I got a **SUSPENDED** lable in main thread,
somebody say the reason maybe **GC** , **Debugger**, **infinite loop**, so I have try **Debugger** and **infinite loop**, and I got the **SUSPENDED** , but the difference is when I use **Debugger** to get ANR, I got **sCount=2 dsCount=1**, and when I use **infinite loop** to get ANR, i got **sCount=1 dsCount=0**..
so What does it mean in an ANR file?
Following is the screenshot of the ANR

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can judge from [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/eclair-release/vm/Thread.c#3284):

```
dvmPrintDebugMessage(target, " | group=\"%s\" sCount=%d dsCount=%d s=%c obj=%p 
                     self=%p\n", 
                     groupName, thread->suspendCount, thread->dbgSuspendCount, 
                     thread->isSuspended ? 'Y' : 'N', thread->threadObj, thread);
```

So, to answer your question:

`sCount` stands for `thread->suspendCount`, `dsCount` stands for `thread->dbgSuspendCount`.